# How to change ListView background and text color without XML

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, colors

I have made a ListView which is populated with elements of an ArrayList. I do not have an XML file with this ListView, it is only in Java. Given this, how would I change the background color of the ListView as well as change the color of the text of the ListView?

This is the code for the ListView:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(CollegeList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameList));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

You have to add an extra parameter to your ArrayAdapter, this will be a CUSTOM XML OF YOUR OWN and the next one will be a textview that is inside that custom layout, that way the array adapter will know which layout to fill and which textview needs to show the data you want to show.

from that xml you can modify background and color. will look something like this:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(CollegeList.this, R.layout.your_custom_layout, R.id.the-text-view-in-that-layout, nameList));
```

Comment: How would I get to the file?

Comment: My mistake, dont modify that file since it is of Android OS, what you should do is create a layout just like this one and set your properties there, i will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But is there a way to do this for other items such a simple_list_item_2?

Comment: Then please mark the answer as correct and make a new one, but if you are planning to make a more complex custom layout, then ArrayAdapter will eventually stop being the best approach, look at the other answer provided by nouseforname as you will be using that a lot more than a simple arrayAdapter in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to customize each line of the listview you have to use a custom adapter with custom listview item. Then you can use the "getView" Method to catch each item and position to change colors.

Here is a sample:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private Context context;
    private int itemResourceId;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutId, ArrayList<Item> items) {
        super(context, layoutId, items);

        this.context = context;
        this.itemResourceId = layoutId;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(itemResourceId, null);
            holder.listItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }   
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        if (position % 2 == 0) 
            view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.listItemEven));
        else
            view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.listItemOdd));

        Item item = items.get(position);
        holder.listItem.setText((position+1) + ". " + item.sTitle);

        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView listItem;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the xml for simple_list_item_1 [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml). You can copy it to your project and modify it, just change the code for your listview to `setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(CollegeList.this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameList));` You can also create one yourself, since simple_list_item_1 is nothing but a textview. Just make sure that the id is `android:id="@android:id/text1"` otherwise it won't work with the default adapter.