# changing the list view of navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer and I have 5 items in that. What I want to do is I want the first 3 items in the list to display from the top than a gap in between and the next two items to be displayed from the bottom of the drawer.
How can I do this?

Basically I want to how can I customise my drawer.

I also want to know from where I can make icons for my navigation drawer.
Here the snapshot to my drawer
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/equu9diwrdaqf8f/Screenshot_2014-08-03-12-22-06.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a custom adapter like always when you want to have something different from standard. There you can add customs views as well.

See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25086380/2777381. this is a sample of an custom adapter.

My idea would be to ad 3 custom listview items, with your icon, then an emty view with specific height. and then again some more custom list items.

Edit:

Sample of an "empty" View which i use as separator line:

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/viewSeparator"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayoutDrive"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/separator"/>
```

Comment: can you tell me how to put a empty view?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose [this post](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) will help you :) Just change DrawerLayout and put here whatever you want

```or-tag-here
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Relativelayout to display Lists -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- Listview to display on top slider menu -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_top_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/list_background"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
        <!-- Listview to display on bottom slider menu -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_bottom_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/list_background"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```